# Aggregation in Drupal 7,many errors

Tags: css-js-aggregation

its always a problems with drupal aggregation,once scripts don't work,
now i get this error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/sites/all/themes/subtheme/js/script.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 4942 of /home/ideald2/domains/idealdesigns.tk/public_html/includes/common.inc).
```

i checked the path but its right,why it says no such file or directory,am tryin to get my portfolio online but been failing since a week,
how to make aggragation without errors

Answer (score -1):

Are you using drupal_add_js()? Make sure you use:

drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/script.js');

aggregation seems to fail otherwise